# Automatically wrap / decorate all pytest unit tests

Tags: python, pytest

Let's say I have a very simple logging decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def my_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"{func.__name__} ran with args: {args}, and kwargs: {kwargs}")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper
```

I can add this decorator to every pytest unit test individually:

```
@my_decorator
def test_one():
    assert True

@my_decorator
def test_two():
    assert 1
```

How can I automatically add this decorator to every single pytest unit test so I don't have to add it manually? What if I want to add it to every unit test in a file? Or in a module?

My use case is to wrap every test function with a SQL profiler, so inefficient ORM code raises an error. Using a pytest fixture should work, but I have thousands of tests so it would be nice to apply the wrapper automatically instead of adding the fixture to every single test. Additionally, there may be a module or two I don't want to profile so being able to opt-in or opt-out an entire file or module would be helpful.

Comment: Can you give some information about your use case? The standard way in pytest would be to use an auto-use fixture, though maybe you want to do something that cannot be done using a fixture?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen just updated the question above with my use case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provided you can move the logic into a fixture, as stated in the question, you can just use an auto-use fixture defined in the top-level `conftest.py`.

To add the possibility to opt out for some tests, you can define a marker that will be added to the tests that should not use the fixture, and check that marker in the fixture, e.g. something like this:

*conftest.py*

```py
import pytest

def pytest_configure(config):
    config.addinivalue_line(
        "markers",
        "no_profiling: mark test to not use sql profiling"
    )

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def sql_profiling(request):
    if not request.node.get_closest_marker("no_profiling"):
        # do the profiling
    yield
```

*test.py*

```py
import pytest

def test1():
    pass # will use profiling

@pytest.mark.no_profiling
def test2():
    pass # will not use profiling
```

As pointed out by @hoefling, you could also disable the fixture for a whole module by adding:

```py
pytestmark = pytest.mark.no_profiling
```

in the module. That will add the marker to all contained tests.

Comment: Nice answer - this also allows turning the fixture off for a whole module by adding a module var `pytestmark = pytest.mark.no_profiling`. No custom decorator should thus be necessary at all!

Comment: I got the following error: `ValueError: unknown configuration value: 'no_profiling'` - but once I removed `pytest_configure` everything worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry - I made an error in the marker registration syntax, corrected it now. Without that you get a warning about an unknown marker.