# override autouse=True pytest fixture

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures, monkeypatching

I have a [pytest fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html) which I need to use in *almost every* test I write:

```
# fixture to mock server response
# autouse=True means that this fixture is included in ALL tests by default
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_server_wrapper(monkeypatch):
    def post_to_server_override():
        class response:
            status_code = 200
        r = response()
        return r
    monkeypatch.setattr(server_wrapper, 'post_to_server', post_to_server_override)
```

Thanks to `autouse=True`, the fixture is used in all of my unit tests.  But what about the one unit test I have where I do *not* want to use the fixture?  How do I disable the fixture for that one test?  I tried this:

```
def test_server(patch_server_wrapper=False):
    some_func_that_calls_server_and_actually_needs_to_hit_it()
```

but it doesn't disable the fixture.  I have a workaround but it's not my favorite.  Is there a builtin way to disable it?  What is the simplest possible solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically wrap / decorate all pytest unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65557740/automatically-wrap-decorate-all-pytest-unit-tests) - the question does not sound like it, but check the answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you!  The title and contents of my question target this situation better than the other question, so I will not delete this question.