# How to Decorate unittest TestCase Class

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I'm trying to create my own decorator for a python unit test My goal is to wrap an entire unittest `TestCase` class and apply certain modifications to it. For some reason, however, the wrapped class seems to be invisible to the test framework.

For these particular tests, I've been trying to use the python built in `unittest` framework. I've also tried using pytest and following along with [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65557740/automatically-wrap-decorate-all-pytest-unit-tests), but I was still unable to get my decorator to work.

Here is what I've tried:

```py
# test_decorator.py
import unittest
import functools

def wrapper_for_test(test_case):
    @functools.wraps(test_case)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return test_case(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@wrapper_for_test
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

I then run the following:

```bash
$ python -m unittest test_decorator.py

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

And the test is not found.

But when I comment out `@wrapper_for_test`, I get:

```bash
$ python -m unittest test_decorator.py

FAIL: test_example (test_decorator.TestClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\test_decorator.py", line 78, in test_example
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

The test fails (as expected).

Why isn't the test found when I use the decorator? How can I wrap a unittest `TestCase` class and have it be found?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that wrapping a class is much different from wrapping a function. Class wrapping is intended to be used for modifying a method of that class. My original intention was to be able to wrap a `TestCase` class to execute some code before any tests were ran, then run more code once all tests were finished. This could be achieved by modifying the `setUpClass()` and `tearDownClass()` methods of the `TestCase` class:

```py
import unittest

def wrapper_for_test(test_case):
    orig_setUpClass = test_case.setUpClass
    orig_tearDownClass = test_case.tearDownClass

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # apply modifications
        print("applying modifications")
        # call original setUpClass()
        return orig_setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # revert modifications
        print("Cleaning up now that all tests have executed")
        # call original tearDownClass()
        return orig_tearDownClass()

    test_case.setUpClass = setUpClass
    test_case.tearDownClass = tearDownClass
    return test_case

@wrapper_for_test
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        print("setting up the class")

    def test_example(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
        self.assertTrue(False)

    def test_two(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, 2)
```

In my case, I ended up going with a modified version of django's [TestContextDecorator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e9fd2b572410b1236da0d3d0933014138d89f44e/django/test/utils.py#L398):

```py
import unittest
import functools


class modify_initial_setup:

    def __init__(self, attr_name=None, kwarg_name=None):
        self.attr_name = attr_name
        self.kwarg_name = kwarg_name

    def enable(self):
        print("Running code before any tests have run")

    def disable(self):
        print("Cleaning up after all tests have finished")

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.enable()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.disable()

    def decorate_class(self, cls):
        if issubclass(cls, unittest.TestCase):
            decorated_setUpClass = cls.setUpClass
            decorated_tearDownClass = cls.tearDownClass

            @classmethod
            def setUpClass(inner_cls: unittest.TestCase):
                context = self.enable()
                if self.attr_name:
                    setattr(inner_cls, self.attr_name, context)
                decorated_setUpClass()

            @classmethod
            def tearDownClass(inner_cls: unittest.TestCase):
                context = self.disable()
                if self.attr_name:
                    setattr(inner_cls, self.attr_name, context)
                decorated_tearDownClass()

            cls.setUpClass = setUpClass
            cls.tearDownClass = tearDownClass
            return cls

        raise TypeError(f"Can only decorate subclasses of unittest.TestCase. Not {cls}")

    def decorate_callable(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            self.enable()
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                raise e
            finally:
                self.disable()

        return inner

    def __call__(self, decorated):
        if isinstance(decorated, type):
            return self.decorate_class(decorated)
        elif callable(decorated):
            return self.decorate_callable(decorated)
        raise TypeError(f"Cannot decorate object of type {type(decorated)}")


@modify_initial_setup()
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    # adding this setUpClass() method isn't necessary. it's just here to show that it still works alongside the wrapper.
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        print("setting up the class")

    def test_example(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
        self.assertTrue(False)

    def test_two(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, 2)
```

And this also allows me to decorate individual test functions in the same way if desired. Note that decorating using this class requires the decorator to be called. So decorate like this `@wrapper_for_test()` instead of `@wrapper_for_test`.

Comment: Why not using inheritance instead?

Comment: Another idea, you mentioned that you were exploring pytest as well. Using pytest fixture with class/module scope and the cleanup to be done after yielding the result might achieve the same result with less code. See https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session for more details.

Comment: @jlandercy If you're suggesting inheriting the Django `TestContextDecorator`, that would also definitely be an option. My goal in this post, however, was more to understand how wrapping a test class could be achieved. So I wanted to post a more all-in-one solution.

Comment: @PeterK Thanks! That's definitely something I should try looking into.

Comment: I highly suggest you look into using pytest.  It is way easier to write tests with.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator should wrap a single function, not the class. So the code should be like this:

```
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @wrapper_for_test
    def test_example(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helps, but I am still unsure about how to wrap an entire unittest `TestCase` class. My goal is to apply certain modifications to an entire `TestCase`. I have edited my question to add more clarity.